# Why are Stylus and Mouse events fired when touching my object?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch

I have a `PushPin` object I have hooked up to a handful of Touch / Stylus / Mouse events:

```
pp.MouseDown += pp_MouseDown;
pp.TouchDown += pp_TouchDown;
pp.TouchUp += pp_TouchUp;
pp.StylusDown += pp_StylusDown;
pp.StylusUp += pp_StylusUp;
```

**Handlers**

```
    void pp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        PushPinUpOrDown(sender);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void pp_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var pushpin = (sender as Pushpin);
        pushpin.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void pp_StylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
    {
        var pushpin = (sender as Pushpin);
        pushpin.CaptureStylus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void pp_StylusUp(object sender, StylusEventArgs e)
    {
        var pushpin = (sender as Pushpin);
        e.Handled = true;
        if (pushpin != null && e.StylusDevice.Captured == pushpin)
        {
            PushPinUpOrDown(sender);
            pushpin.ReleaseStylusCapture();
        }

    }

    void pp_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var pushpin = (sender as Pushpin);
        e.Handled = true;
        if (pushpin != null && e.TouchDevice.Captured == pushpin)
        {
            PushPinUpOrDown(sender);
            pushpin.ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);

        }
    }
```

but when I touch my `PushPin` firstly the `StylusDown` event fires then followed by the `MouseDown`. The `TouchDown` event I would expect to fire never fires.

Why is this? is this a problem with my program or my monitor?

Do I need both Stylus and Touch events?

(I am using a touch enabled monitor not tablet or anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692286/WPF-and-multi-touch) I got the code:

```
    void pp_StylusDown(Object sender, StylusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            //Capture the touch device (i.e. finger on the screen)
            e.StylusDevice.Capture(sender as Pushpin);
        }
    }

    void pp_StylusUp(Object sender, StylusEventArgs e)
    {
        var device = e.StylusDevice;

        if (sender != null && device.Captured == sender as Pushpin)
        {
            (sender as Pushpin).ReleaseStylusCapture();
            PushPinUpOrDown(sender, true);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

which stopped the `MouseDown` event firing. The main reason (strangely) was removing `e.Handled = true` from `pp_StylusDown` fixed the problem

Still doesn't explain why the stylus event fires when touching the screen